# Automated text file Editing

Tags: text, editing

I have a text file that looks something similar to this:

```
+PhoneNumber          3/5/15 7:16 PM          us          Text is here
+PhoneNumber          3/5/15 7:16 PM          us          Text is here
+PhoneNumber          3/5/15 7:16 PM          us          Text is here
+PhoneNumber          3/5/15 7:16 PM          us          Text is here
```

Now the problem is some lines does this:

```
+PhoneNumber          3/5/15 7:16 PM          us          Text is here
but runs down to here 
+PhoneNumber          3/5/15 7:16 PM          us          Text is here
+PhoneNumber          3/5/15 7:16 PM          us          Text is here
but runs down to here 
+PhoneNumber          3/5/15 7:16 PM          us          Text is here
but runs down to here or even
longer like this
```

Now I have lines that vary in length, and do things like the above examples. My goal is I need every single line to look like the first example. IE I want every line to begin with the "+PhoneNumber" not text. All of the text should be backspaced up to it's previous line so it finishes the sentence. So it would be more like this:

```
+PhoneNumber          3/5/15 7:16 PM          us          Text is here but runs down to here 
+PhoneNumber          3/5/15 7:16 PM          us          Text is here
+PhoneNumber          3/5/15 7:16 PM          us          Text is here but runs down to here 
+PhoneNumber          3/5/15 7:16 PM          us          Text is here but runs down to here or even longer like this
```

I am completely at a loss at how to get a script or anything to do this for me, so I'm asking for assistance. I've tried googling it and nothing is of any assistance. For now I am editing every line by hand, but there are over 30000 lines of text, and to edit all that by hand would take forever. So any assistance would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks guys!

TLDR; Need a script that will back text up to the previous line if the line it is on doesn't start with a +

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suggest to use two expression first replace \r\n with space and then (.*?)+ replace with $1\r\n+

in notepad++ for quick output

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to awk:

```
~ $ cat test.awk
/^\+/ { printf "\n%s", $0; }
/^[^+]/ { printf " %s", $0; }
END { print ""; }

~ $ cat test.input
+PhoneNumber          3/5/15 7:16 PM          us          Text is here
but runs down to here
+PhoneNumber          3/5/15 7:16 PM          us          Text is here
+PhoneNumber          3/5/15 7:16 PM          us          Text is here
but runs down to here
+PhoneNumber          3/5/15 7:16 PM          us          Text is here
but runs down to here or even
longer like this

~ $ awk -f test.awk <test.input  | tail +2
+PhoneNumber          3/5/15 7:16 PM          us          Text is here but runs down to here
+PhoneNumber          3/5/15 7:16 PM          us          Text is here
+PhoneNumber          3/5/15 7:16 PM          us          Text is here but runs down to here
+PhoneNumber          3/5/15 7:16 PM          us          Text is here but runs down to here or even longer like this
```